# Displaying objects inside an array in a html table

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I'm trying to make my program store and displayed the user input in the array. So it must take user input, store it in the array and then render that to the html and add it to the table.
So far it can display what is already in the array but once it takes the user input it does store it in the array but doesn't render it.

```js
let books = [
    {
    title: "Naruto",
    author: "kishimoto",
    Pages: 400,
    status: true
},
{
    title: "One Piece",
    author: "Oda",
    Pages: 3000,
    status: false
}
];

function popForm(){
    $("#popup").removeClass("hide");
}

function hideForm(){
    $("#popup").addClass("hide");
    $("#main-page").removeClass("hide");
}

function toggle (){
    $("#main-page").addClass("hide");
   
}

const addBook = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let book = {
        title: $("#title").val(),
        author: $("#author").val(),
        pages: $("#pages").val(),
        status: $("#status").val()
    }

    books.push(book);
    document.forms[0].reset();
    
    localStorage.setItem('myMangaList', JSON.stringify(books));
    
    
}


let table = document.getElementById('di-books');
books.forEach(book => {
    let tr = document.createElement('tr');
    Object.entries(book).forEach(value => { 
       let td = document.createElement('td');
       td.innerHTML= value;
       tr.appendChild(td);
    });
    table.appendChild(tr);
    
    
});
```

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

table {

  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  /* border: 1px solid #dddddd; */
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px;
}


#addBook {
  border-radius: 70%;
  background-color: #48abe0;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 31px;
  height: 65px;
  width: 65px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px darkslategray;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 25px;
  right: 25px;
}

.popup {
  /* background-color:; */
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: width 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55), height 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55),
    top 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  top: 30%;
  /* box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px darken($royal, 40%); */
  border-radius: 7px;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<!-- fonts -->
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link
    href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Edu+NSW+ACT+Foundation:wght@500&family=Edu+QLD+Beginner:wght@400;600;700&family=Edu+TAS+Beginner:wght@700&family=Josefin+Sans:wght@300&family=Montserrat:wght@100;600&family=Mouse+Memoirs&family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,500;1,200&family=Quicksand:wght@300&family=Ubuntu:wght@300&family=Work+Sans:wght@200&display=swap"
    rel="stylesheet">
<h1>Manga Library</h1>

<div id="popup" class="hide">
    <form>
        <label for="title">Manga Title:</label>
        <input type="text" id="title" name="title">

        <label for="author">Author:</label>
        <input type="text" id="author" name="author">

        <label for="pages">Pages:</label>
        <input type="text" id="pages" name="pages">

        <label for="status">Status:</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="status" name="status">

        <button type="submit" id="submit" onclick="addBook(event); hideForm()" >Submit</button>

    </form>
</div>


<!-- onclick="addBook() -->
<div id="main-page">
    <h1>list</h1>
    <div id="books-grid">
        <table id="di-books">
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Author</th>
                <th>Pages</th>
                <th>Status</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <button id="addBook" onclick="popForm(); toggle()">+</button>

</div>

<!-- JQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please add the HTML that this script needs. You can create a runnable snippet using the toolbar.

Comment: I'm trying to edit the code to add html but it's telling me the format doesn't work

Comment: There is a button on the toolbar `<>` which inserts a template for a runnable snippet: in it there are three sections to fill in: the HTML, the CSS, the JS.

Comment: I've done that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should update DOM content after pushing new book to the books array,
Try this code :

```js
function addBookToTable(book) {
      let table = document.getElementById("di-books");
      
      let tr = document.createElement("tr");
      Object.entries(book).forEach((value) => {
        let td = document.createElement("td");
        td.innerHTML = value;
        tr.appendChild(td);
      });
      table.appendChild(tr);
}

// then use it in your addBook function 
const addBook = (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      let book = {
        title: $("#title").val(),
        author: $("#author").val(),
        pages: $("#pages").val(),
        status: $("#status").val(),
      };

      books.push(book);
      document.forms[0].reset();
      // Update DOM
      addBookToTable(book) 
      localStorage.setItem("myMangaList", JSON.stringify(books));
};
```

Comment: It works, if you have time please explain to me what exactly i was doing wrong i want to learn from my mistakes.

Comment: So in your html page was not updated after adding new book to the books array, because it's charged (document is loaded). 
In this case, if you want to change the document content you should interact with the DOM and add elements to it, and by using "table.appendChild(tr);" you will update the table content.

Comment: So I have to kind of reload the page so that it now reads elements that have been added to the array?

Comment: Yeah and no, let me explain : 
- You have added your new book the localstorage of the browser by using : " localStorage.setItem('myMangaList', JSON.stringify(books));" but you did not use this item in your code . If you reload the page you will get only the two items declared in the books array, but if you look at your localstorage content you'll find it
- So you should first initialize the books array from your localstorage after loading the html page

Comment: I think I get it. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Your are welcome, you can mark the question as resolved if you think that it's answered your question

Comment: Now i don't know where to do that, this is my first post ever lol.

Comment: I've done that, again thank you so much for helping me have a wonderful day just like you've made mine, thank you.